How to use SwiftUI simultaneousGesture and UIViewRepresentable
Given the following code
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      MyButton()
        .simultaneousGesture(
          TapGesture(count: 1).onEnded { print("\(#function)") },
          including: .all
        )
    }
}

struct MyButton: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    config.image = UIImage(systemName: "hand.tap.fill")

   let button = UIButtonSubclass()
    button.configuration = config
    return button
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {
  }
}


class UIButtonSubclass: UIButton {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  @objc private func didTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("\(#function)")
  }
}

Notice:

The UIViewRepresentable implementation has a .touchUpInside action
In ContentView, MyButton registers an simultaneousGesture

When executing the code, tapping on the button, only executes the TapGesture, never the touchUpInside handle.
If the TapGesture is not recognized (like if I set tap count to be 2) then touchUpInside handle is executed.
Is it possible for TapGesture gesture to work simultaneous with the touchUpInside handle ?
Aditional notes:

The UIButtonSubclass comes from an external library and can not change it.


Why not just do whatever you want to do in didTap? Have MyButton take an additional closure and pass it to UIButtonSubclass.

@Sweeper yea, that would work, but for my case, the didTap is done by an external lib and I don't have access to it.
And the TapGesture is done by from my app, but it's in a component that I reuse.

If you have access and can pass the action in the UIViewRepresentable that might be the simpler way, but for the situation the OP looks like UITapGestureRecognizer somehow works.
struct MyButton: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    config.image = UIImage(systemName: "hand.tap.fill")

    let button = UIButtonSubclass()
    button.configuration = config

    let internalTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
      target: context.coordinator,
      action: #selector(Coordinator.handleInternalTap))
    internalTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    button.addGestureRecognizer(internalTapGesture)
    return button
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject {
    @objc func handleInternalTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      guard let button = gesture.view as? UIControl else { return }
      button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
  }
}

Note, the UITapGestureRecognizer action will always be called on user tap, even if highPriorityGesture is used from SwiftUI side.
